# WebView2 log http traffic (inbound and outbound)

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2

As stated in the title i'm interested in the management (reading is sufficient by now) of the the incoming and outgoing data from the WebView2 istance user are using.

I'have try do add listener to WebMessageResourceRequested and WebMessageReceived but i have the sensation i missinterpreted their behaviour becasue they don't work as i expected (so is very likely that i am using that handler in a wrong way)

```
public partial class SimpleWebView2 : Form
{
    public SimpleWebView2 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Initialization();
    }

    private async void Initialization ()
    {
        await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
        webView21.CoreWebView2.WebResourceRequested += new EventHandler<CoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventArgs>(this.webView21_WebMessageResourceRequested);
    }

    private void webView21_WebMessageResourceRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
         //does not fire
    }
}
```

Comment: i found my fault.
i had to initialize the filter for the request i'am interested in before use the handler.
webView.CoreWebView2.AddWebResourceRequestedFilter("*", CoreWebView2WebResourceContext.All)

Comment: You seems to have solved the subject issue. Just in case any further hints are still needed there here is a good article ["Using the WebView control to capture HTTP Request Content"](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2021/Aug/18/Using-the-WebView-control-to-capture-Request-Content)

Answer (score 0):

A common solution is Fiddler. Just start it and you'll see the inbound and outbound traffic of any application, including the one that is using WebView2.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case, something must be intercepting the requests before they get to Fiddler....or something?  95% of the time Fiddler doesn't see any traffic from my WebView2 application.

Comment: @JasonBarkley Depending on the nature of your application and system, it can be the case. Have you read the fiddler documentation? This one: https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configuredotnetapp